# Convergence as surely Bernoulli r.v

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,  .  .  .$ be  an  i.i.d.  sequence  of  Bernoulli  random variables  with  parameter $p \in (0,1)$. Set $T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{1}[X_i=1]$. Prove that $P(T=\infty)=1$.

Set $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}[X_i=1]$. Then $\mathbb E(S_n)=np$ where $p$ is the probability of success for Bernoulli r.v. Note $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(S_n) = \infty$,  $ P(T=\infty) = \infty$. Then By Borel Cantelli 2, $P({S_n \operatorname{ i.o.}}) = P(T=\infty) = 1$

Is this correct? Please suggest corrections in the process. Thanks!

Comment: $P(S_n) = np$? what does $P(\cdot)$ means?

Comment: P(.) = Probability. I am perhaps wrong on P(Sn) = np. I was thinking since we are summing r.v. that occur, we would be summing up their probabilities since they are all Bernoulli.

Comment: The probability of what? you haven't define an event, i'm guessing there should've been $\mathbb{E} S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = np$.

Comment: also, $\sum P(T)$ doesn't make any sense either. what are you summing up?

Comment: there is still mistakes/typos in your question. Let me post the answer as I see and you'll correct your solution. The approach is correct though

Comment: Starting at "Note $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(S_n) = \infty$", you seem to be aligning words you do not know the meaning of... this is disquieting.

Comment: Yes, I made some massive mistakes. Need to clear my basics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_n := \{ X_n = 1 \}$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(E_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = \infty \implies \mathbb{P}(E_n \text{ i. o. }) = \mathbb{P}(T = \infty) = 1,$$
by second Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Answer (score 1):

According to SLLN
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I_i \xrightarrow{a.s.} p, 
$$
hence your sequence is 
$$
a_n \cdot \frac{T}{a_n},
$$
where $a_n = n$, thus 
$$
n \frac{T}{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} \infty p = \infty.
$$